# What don't I understand about import/export in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I created a native module library for android and am trying to merge into an existing project with similar functionality for iOS. The API is a bit different, and I'm not good with Objective-C, so in `index.js` I want to call the iOS function, intercept the callback in javascript, massage the results into my new API, and call the original callback. For now I want to use a different name for the new API call rather than the one defined in the iOS native module (`colorGrabber.getColors`) So I define a function `getSome`

I've tried many combinations of different export expressions and import expressions and I always get errors either like `_reactNativeColorGrabber2.default.getSome is not a function` or `( is not a function. (In '(0,_reactNativeColorGrabber2.default)','(' is an instance of Object)`.

I haven't a clue what these messages mean. So in the style of a clueless hacker, I try to copy what other people of done. In `react-native-image-picker`, they have something similar. They say:

```
module.exports = {
  ...ImagePickerManager,
  showImagePicker: function showImagePicker(options, callback) {
    if (typeof options === 'function') {
      callback = options;
      options = {};
    }
    return ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker({...DEFAULT_OPTIONS, ...options}, callback)
  }
}
```

It works for them. But when I try something very similar:

```
module.exports = {
  getSome: function getSome(image, callback) {
    return colorGrabber.getColors(image, callback);
  }
}
```

the error message says the function is not defined. I've tried different forms of ES6-style export statements as well.

In the consuming component I've tried both `import colorGrabber from 'react-native-color-grabber';` (which gives the first error message I mentioned above) and `import getSome from 'react-native-color-grabber';` which gives the second.

Clearly there's something basic about importing and exporting I don't  understand.

Clues, anyone?

UPDATE: It appears that most of my experiments were foiled by packager caching--- that's probably why I couldn't get things to work. Much of the time when I would change something it would be very puzzling because the result wouldn't change. It seems like the packager may ignore changes in node_modules. I'm having success now if every time I make a change in index.js I kill the packager and execute `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-* && npm start` then reload my simulator.

Comment: try `import { getSome } from 'react-native-color-grabber'`

Comment: Native will not expose any methods to JavaScript unless explicitly told to. =

Comment: Did you read any documentation about `import` and `export`? [MDN - `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [MDN - `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: @FelixKling yes I did but obviously I did not understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const getSome = (image, callback) => (
    colorGrabber.getColors(image, callback)
  )
```

You should be able to import it now using `import { getSome } from '../filepath'`

Comment: That works! Could you please add a little info to explain why? This is ES7 syntax isn't it?

Comment: Sure, the import/export syntax or the syntax of the function?

Comment: @chetstone: It's ES6 (ES2015). Why it works? `export const getSome = ...;` creates a *named export* with name `getSome`. `import { getSome } from '../filepath'` is a *named import* that imports the export with name `getSome`.

Comment: @MattAft the function syntax.

Comment: @FelixKling I think I understand the import/export now. My problem was probably more with the packager as I explain in the update to my question.

Comment: @chetstone: Ahh, caching... and best and the worst thing.

Comment: @chetstone arrow syntax has an implicit return, you could write it all on one line if you wanted to like `export const getSome = (image, callback) => colorGrabber.getColors(image, callback)`, but the parentheses let you wrap it.